# Rename levels using wildcard matching in python

Tags: python

How to replace the levels using wildcard matching in Python?

I have a column named years of experience, values as

```
"0 YEAR, 9 MONTHS", 
"1 YEAR, 0 MONTHS", 
"1 YEAR, 1 MONTHS", 
"1 YEAR, 10 MONTHS", 
"1 YEAR, 9 MONTHS", 
"10 YEAR, 0 MONTHS", 
"10 YEAR, 1 MONTHS", 
"10 YEAR, 10 MONTHS",
```

like-wise nearly 600 levels;

I wish to bucket all

- "0 YEAR... as "<1",
- 1 YEAR as "1",
- 2 YEAR as "2",
- 3 YEAR as "3",
- 4 YEAR as "4",
- more than 5 YEAR as ">5",

giving 6 levels in total.

Comment: Please provide what you have tried to achieve this? also did you mean to say `3 YEAR as "3",` ?

Comment: yes, just edited

Comment: also what code have you tried to achieve it!

Comment: I used in R, yrs <- dfyr %>%
  mutate(yr = as.numeric(gsub(" YEAR.*$", "", yrs)),
    bucket = case_when(yr < 1 ~ "<1",
                       yr >= 5 ~ ">=5",
                       TRUE ~ as.character(yr)))

Comment: I meant what you tried in python, not in R :)

Comment: data['Service'].str[:2] then data['Service'].astype(int)

Comment: In the question please, and provide code which can actually run!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it works for me.

```py
import math

# samples ...
years_of_experience = [
  "0 YEAR, 9 MONTHS", 
  "1 YEAR, 0 MONTHS", 
  "2 YEAR, 1 MONTHS", 
  "5 YEAR, 11 MONTHS"
]

for y in years_of_experience:
  year, month = [int(s) for s in y.split() if s.isdigit()]
  years = math.floor((year * 12 + month) / 12)
  if years < 1:
    print('<1')
  elif years > 4:
    print('>5')
  else:
    print(years)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
myarr = ["0 YEAR, 9 MONTHS", "1 YEAR, 0 MONTHS", "1 YEAR, 1 MONTHS", "1 YEAR, 
10 MONTHS", "1 YEAR, 9 MONTHS", "10 YEAR, 0 MONTHS", "10 YEAR, 1 MONTHS", "10 
YEAR, 10 MONTHS",]
for date in myarr:
    year = int(date.split()[0])
    if year<1:
        print("<1")
    elif year>=5:
        print(">5")
    else:
        print(year)
```

Output is :

<1
1
1
1
1
>5
>5

Answer (score 0):

Found this,also works

```
df['Service_Year'] = df['YYMM_of_Service'].str[:2].astype(int)
df['Service_Year'] = pd.cut(df['Service_Year'], bins=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], labels=['<1','2','3','4','>5'])
```